# Checking a HDD's health in Raid?

Tags: raid, software-raid, smartctl

I have a few HDDs in an Ubuntu SW-RAID array, and now I came across to quite a number of questions sticking together:

1.) Is it safe to do `smartctl -t` (SMART selftest) while the drive is part of an array without causing any harms on data?

2.) Should I somehow stop the RAID, making as inactive, or unmount it before doing the selftest?

3.) There is a drive which never done any self-test. How can it have still have SMART attributes?

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, according to the docs.  Personally I always do it just after a level 0 backup, but then I'm a coward having learnt the hard way!
2. No need, see 1) above.
3. Look for the following three lines:

```
SMART Status not supported: Incomplete response, ATA output registers missing
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
Warning: This result is based on an Attribute check.
```

It just reads the attributes.